# How did Hitler get the idea for the title “My Struggle”?

Tags: inspiration, german-language, title, mein-kampf, adolf-hitler

Are there any records elaborating on how Hitler came up with the title for his book? Were there any previous books he was emulating or alluding to? Was he influenced by some literary style in his environs? Or, does he give any account somewhere, in conversation or letters, of what thinking/gestation process caused the idea to come into his head. Why did he like it, why did he choose it for a title (perhaps there were alternative ideas for a title), and why did he settle on it?

Answer (score 3):

According to Richard Cohen in the [New York Times](https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/books/98/06/28/bookend/bookend.html):

> Its original title was "A Four-and-a-Half-Year Struggle Against Lies, Stupidity and Cowardice," but Hitler's publisher, Max Amann of Franz Eher Verlag, who had been Hitler's company commander during World War I, persuaded him to use the shorter version.

This appears to be a widely accepted fact, as an internet search of the alternate title phrase turns up many corroborating sources.